# Is dfs or bfs better for testing bipartite on directed graphs?

Tags: time-complexity, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

If I want to check for two test colourbility / if a **directed** graph is bipartite, does it matter if I use Breadth First Search or Depth First Search? Is one more efficient in terms of time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

It actually doesn't matter at all whether the graph is directed or undirected; whichever direction the edge is, the two nodes on either end of it must have different colours. So the answer is entirely the same for undirected graphs.

I'll also assume that the graph is connected so that every node is reachable from `node_0`; this won't really make a difference because either way you will just run the algorithm independently on each connected component. But it does simplify the analysis.

Either DFS or BFS looks like the below. The only difference is the behaviour of `to_visit.get_one()` and `to_visit.put_one()`; DFS uses a stack (last in, first out) whereas BFS uses a queue (first in, first out).

```py
def is_bipartite(node_0):
    to_visit = [node_0]
    colors = { node_0: 'RED' }

    while to_visit:
        node = to_visit.get_one()
        color1 = colors[node]
        color2 = 'BLUE' if color1 == 'RED' else 'RED'

        for neighbour in node.neighbours:
            if neighbour not in colors:
                colors[neighbour] = color2
                to_visit.put_one(neighbour)
            elif colors[neighbour] == color1:
                return False

    return True
```

Considering the time-complexity of the algorithms, in either case:

1. Every node is inserted into `to_visit` at most once, because it's only inserted if it's not already in `colors`, but we add it to `colors` when we insert it.
2. We iterate over `node.neighbours` at most once, because of 1.

So the worst case number of iterations is the same for both algorithms; O(E) where E is the number of edges in the graph.